# Why the Condition if(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0) is failed?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

**Question:** Why following Servlet is printing "**other thing happened**". Structures of LoginServlet and index.jsp are following. I am using Netbeans 8.1 and ApacheTomcat 8.0.9.0 and browser is chrome.

**Structure of LoginServlet**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {  
        String contentType=request.getContentType();
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        //Why the following condition is failed. 
        if((contentType!=null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0)){//<==see this

            DataInputStream in =new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();
            out.print("contentType is not null");
            byte [] dataBytes=new byte[formDataLength];
        }        
        if(contentType==null)
            out.print("contentType is null");
        else
            out.print("other thing happended");//<== Why this is printing
    }
```

**Structure of index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoginServlet" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Output of the browser is "**other thing happened**".

Comment: Why don't you just print out the `contentType`?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I want to know in which condition it fails?

Comment: Obviously the contentType isn't null thus it's safe to assume that contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0 is not what you are expecting it to be. 

Like @Sotirios said, inspect the content type. The best way to do that is use the debugger and put a breakpoint at the line that is failing.

Comment: Yaa, I known this is printing because it fails that condition,I want known reason why it is failing. That why I given you LoginServlet and Index.jsp

Comment: If you just `System.out.println(contentType);` you'll know exactly what the value is that the client is sending. This question is completely pointless.

Comment: Why it's failing has nothing do with why it's printing "other thing happened". It's printing that because the body has a content type.

Comment: Dear @Sotirios Delimanolis, If you are giving answer, please read question carefully before doing it is negative. Following is the answer I was looking. Thanks to user3087839.

Comment: You ask _what is mime type of the body of the request?_. You can easily answer this yourself by checking the value of `contentType`. The result you see in your servlet is a direct consequence of that value. You've made no effort to check this yourself. That is why I've downvoted your question.

Comment: Dear  @Sotirios Delimanolis, It was my second question.

Comment: Your first question can be answered by answering your second question. Your second question can be answered by inspecting the value. There is nothing useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

If you want to upload a file, your content-type is multipart/form-data
I guess your success case is uploading file.

Your form just submits an input so you get the "other thing happened"

```
<form action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- code -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for your replay. It must be resason.